# How can i sedn extra data to payment function in contract with QR code

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, cryptocurrency

What i am trying to do is make payment to contract with extra data using qr code. I found some string using to make payment
`ethereum:0x0670e1194ecE93e12D8A4Cc8D67b025f111F9C0a?amount=0.01&data=tagone5` this is my contract on BSC mainnet.

When i use this contract on remix i can make payment with MetaMask. but when i generate qr code and wanna pya by Ledger through my phone. Transaction is failed.

this is payment function

```
function receivePayment(string memory tag) public payable {
    bytes32 tagBytes = stringToBytes32(tag);
    payments[tagBytes] += msg.value;
}

function stringToBytes32(string memory str) pure internal returns (bytes32 result) {
    require(bytes(str).length <= 32, "String is too long to convert to bytes32");
    assembly {
        result := mload(add(str, 32))
    }
}
```

questio is, can i make payment to contract with add extra data like tag (string)? or is not possible